# Why is there a yellow light on my Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I have an original Wii model that I bought recently. I have never used a Wii before, and in the user manual, it says that the power light should be red when off. However, sometimes it is yellow, and I am worried that this may be a malfunction. What does the yellow light mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reference to the above question: [techforums.nintendo.com/thread/2328](http://techforums.nintendo.com/thread/2328)

The yellow light indicates that the Wii is off but the WiiConnect24 is on, operating in [standby](https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/latam/en/systems/wii/ht_settings.jsp?menu=wiiConnect24&submenu=rvl-ht-sett-connect24-activate-standby) mode. You can [turn this light off](https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/latam/en/systems/wii/ht_settings.jsp?menu=wiiConnect24&submenu=rvl-ht-sett-connect24-deactivate) by going to (Wii Icon) > Settings > WiiConnect24 > WiiConnect24 > Off and select Confirm.

At times, you will also see the Wii's disc slot glow. This means that there is new information received over the internet (messages, new Shop content, forecast alerts, etc.), and can be [adjusted](https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/latam/en/systems/wii/ht_settings.jsp?menu=wiiConnect24&submenu=rvl-ht-sett-connect24-slot-light), or even turned off, at any time.

Comment: It would have been nice, however, if Nintendo had informed us in the _user manuals_ about the yellow light!

Comment: It is recommended to do a system update if you leave your Wii connected.  Very early versions of the firmware will overheat the device because the fan does not turn on when the device retrieves data from the internet.

Comment: **Because the [Nintendo Wi-Fi Connection service was closed in 2014](http://www.nintendo.com/whatsnew/detail/vyWpoM6CBIe6FjW8NIY7bvzOrgBURhzw), some features of WiiConnect24 will not work.** This does not mean that the Wii can't use the internet, as such functions like the Shop Channel are still active.